# One if statement doesn't work and the rest do (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, game-development

So, I'm working on a game and the way to level up is through the `money` variable. I decided to use an interval and run the function `upc` every 0.099 seconds and when I run the code, you can get up to about at the point where it says `if(money > 1000005 && Cookies.get*("modal2alrshown")`.  The `Cookies.get` is just a JS library.

```
function upc(){
  if(money > 1000){
    irp.style.display = "inline";
    irptxt.style.display = "inline";
    irpbtn.style.display="inline";
   } else {
    return false
  }
  if(money > 1005 && Cookies.get("modal1alrshown") != "yep"){
    npamodal("./assets/iron_pickaxe.png","Iron Pickaxe")
    Cookies.set("modal1alrshown","yep");
  }
  if(money > 1000000){
    gp.style.display = "inline";
    gptxt.style.display = "inline";
    gpbtn.style.display="inline"
  } else {
    return false;
  }
  if(money > 1000005 && Cookies.get("modal2alrshown") != "yep"){
    npamodal("./assets/gold_pickaxe.png","Gold Pickaxe")
    Cookies.set("modal2alrshown","yep");
  } else {
    return false;
  }
  if(money > 5000000){
    bgep.style.display = "inline";
    bgptxt.style.display = "inline";
    bgpbtn.style.display="inline";
  } else {
    return false;
  }
  if(money > 5000005 ){
    upcontent.innerHTML = "<div id='up1-close'>To exit, click on sky</div><h1 style='text-align:center;'>New Pickaxe Availible!</h1><img src='./assets/baguettepick.png' height='120px'>Baguette Pickaxe<br>And you got a <br><h3>Travel Ticket<img src='./assets/travelticket.png' height='20px'></h3>"
    $("#up1-content, #up1-background").toggleClass("active");
    Cookies.set("modal3alrshown","yep");
    Cookies.set("travelTicket","1");
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: What does it mean `not working`?

Comment: And what `if` are we talking about?

Comment: @Andreas the last two if statements don't work

Comment: @KonradLinkowski what do you mean?

Comment: Perhaps one of the previous `if`s is not fulfilled, so you `return` from your function without ever reaching the last two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be that one of your if statements that return from the function  have a false expression

```
// Potentially this is the faulty expression
if(money > 1000005 && Cookies.get("modal2alrshown") != "yep"){
    ....
} else { 
    // Causing this return to fire, exiting the function
    return false;
}
```

Comment: This should be a comment. You are guessing what OP might has done.

Answer (score 0):

If statement will always work. You need to debug that either `money > 1000005` to be true or `Cookies.get("modal2alrshown") != "yep"` should be true.